# How to implement Add,Edit,Delete in CheckedListBox C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkedlistbox

Currently I have this code to Add an Item in CheckedListBox

```
var items = DomainGroupCheckedListBox.Items;
items.Clear();
items.Add(result[DropDownDomainIDs.SelectedIndex]);
```

But how will I implement it to be like this?

[image]

Meaning if the user click Edit then it can edit the checked field

Comment: Create a dialog containing a `TextBox` and an `OK` and `Cancel` button. Then pass text of checked item to the dialog and show the dialog. Then check if the dialog result is `OK` set  the entered value as item at checked index.

Comment: Nice idea, I'm going to implement it

Comment: The dialog containing TextBox and an OK and Cancel Button should be in seperate form?

Comment: Yes, it's a new form.

Comment: OK. Thank you for your insights

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save the state of the ckeckedButton when user click Edit, you can create an on_click event which trigger saving the state of each élément in your list

1. Here is how to create an event waiting for button to be hit :
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd553231.aspx
2. When you create the event, a new fonction will be generated inside your code, dont change its parameters. You code will look somethig like.

```
    private void ButtonEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         foreach (var item in items)
        {
            bool itemIsChecked = item.Checked;
            // Now you know that this item is checked or not
        }
    }
```